# How can I specify a SHA-256 algorithm for signing the certificate?

Tags: saml, cas, sign

I built an Apereo CAS demo server with a WAR overlay (with which
different services should be authenticated).

I have set up delegated authentication with SAML2 (for integrating
with italian SPID system), following this guide
https://apereo.github.io/2019/02/25/cas61-delegate-authn-saml2-idp/

I copied the SP metadata to a IDP configuration.
This IDP is a test IDP instance, meant to check if SP metadata and the SAML request are ok.

When I run the server and I browse it,
I can see the second login form, but when I click it, the validation checks shows some errors.
Among them there is the following:

```
"The certificate must be signed with a valid algorithm."
"The certificate must not be signed using the SHA1 algorithm (deprecated)."
```

I am pretty sure that SHA-256 would be fine with the IDP validator.

In the documentation
https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/integration/Delegate-Authentication-SAML.html
I see that the following parameter should be in charge of specifying
the signing certificate algorithm:

```
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[].signature-algorithms:
```

Its description is

```
# Required: false
# Type: java.util.List<String>
# Owner: org.apereo.cas.configuration.model.support.pac4j.saml.Pac4jSamlClientProperties
# Module: cas-server-support-pac4j-webflow
# Collection of signing signature algorithms, if any, to override the global defaults.
# cas.authn.pac4j.saml[].signature-algorithms:
```

I don't know what values are allowed there. I googled a lot but with no luck.

I have tried to set that list like this
`cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].signature-algorithms=["sha256WithRSAEncryption"]`,
`cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].signature-algorithms=["SHA256withRSA"]` but,
after clicking the SAML login button, I always get the following
error:

```
org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: Could not determine the signature parameters
    at org.pac4j.saml.crypto.DefaultSignatureSigningParametersProvider.build(DefaultSignatureSigningParametersProvider.java:60)
    ...
```

How can I specify a SHA-256 algorithm for signing the certificate?